amplify configure : Error fetching release: unable to verify the first certificate
I did this "npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli"
and then I did "amplify configure"
but, I have an error "Downloading release from https://package.cli.amplify.aws/12.11.1/amplify-pkg-win-x64.tgz"
"Error fetching release: unable to verify the first certificate"
any idea??
I tried "npm config set strict-ssl false" but no results
